# ksh + print the last value from parameter without print the $parameter

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I need advice - how to print the same last value in ksh scripts without to print param argument

so what we can do in ksh inorder to print the last value ?

example - I need to print the last value ( in this case -$ETH_PORT ) , without to define  $ETH_PORT parameter after the second echo command

how to print the last value from the last echo/print command?

```
 function test


 {

  ETH_PORT=eth0
  echo $ETH_PORT

     # now I need to print the last value ( in this case value from $ETH_PORT param )


  echo < what need to write in order to print last value >

   }


 test
```

expected output after runing the test function

```
   eth0

   eth0
```

Comment: What is a "last value"? `$_` is certainly nothing such in perl, it's just a variable.

Comment: yes I know I give $_ variable as only example for perl

Comment: Perhaps you should just describe what you want to extract with an example.

Comment: I fail to see the point of your question. If you want the value of `$ETH_PORT`, why not use that variable? That would only be useful if you had no way of knowing which value came last, which is not the case here. There is no such "memory" variable in perl that remembers the last value used, and I doubt ksh/bash does.

Comment: @TLP yes your answer logical , but in my ksh script I can’t use the variable because some reasons , so I want to find some way to return and print the last value from the last printed variable

Comment: If I were you, I would post the actual code I am having trouble with, instead of asking how to fix your solution to a problem we know nothing of.

Comment: Why don't you just `echo $ETH_PORT` twice?

Comment: because some internal resons - its about some security ishues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subvert `echo` with a function that kept track of the last thing echo'ed, but that wouldn't capture the last thing to go to `stdout`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function echo {
    /bin/echo $*
    last_echoed="$*"
}

function testit {
    ETH_PORT=eth0
    echo "this is not echo'ed twice"
    echo $ETH_PORT
    echo $last_echoed
}

testit
```

A second option is to use a wrapper script that keeps track of what the last line was and then print it at the end.

Comment: Instead of the external `/bin/echo`, I would use `builtin echo` which executes the builtin `echo` bypassing the function of the same name. Both Bash and KornShell have it.